Soft deletion in many-to-many relationships with through model in Django
I'm facing an issue in my Django project related to soft deletion in many-to-many relationships using a through model. I'd appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this issue.
I have three models in my application: Author, Book, and BookAuthor. The many-to-many relationship between Author and Book is defined through the BookAuthor model. Here are the definitions of my models:
from django.db import models

class Author(SoftDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(SoftDeleteModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='BookAuthor', related_name='books')

class BookAuthor(SoftDeleteModel):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        # Other necessary meta definitions
        pass

The issue arises when I soft delete a relationship in the BookAuthor model and then try to access the books of an author using the query author.books.all(). Even though I have soft deleted the relationship in BookAuthor, I still see all the books associated with the author.
I'm using the django-soft-delete package (https://pypi.org/project/django-soft-delete/),
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can address this issue and ensure that softly deleted relationships are not displayed when accessing through the many-to-many relationship?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Have you ever managed to get this sorted?
I'm going through the same problem at the moment.

@PeterD Yes! I posted the solution in the original post

After some further investigation, I managed to resolve the issue by modifying the SoftDeleteManager provided by the django-soft-delete package. Here's the modified SoftDeleteManager with additional logic to filter out softly deleted relationships when accessed through a many-to-many relationship:
from django.db import models
from soft_delete.managers import SoftDeleteQuerySet

class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SoftDeleteQuerySet(self.model, self._db).filter(is_deleted=False)

    def _apply_soft_delete_filter(self, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(is_deleted=False)

    def _apply_soft_delete_filter_if_needed(self, queryset):
        if self.__class__.__name__ == 'ManyRelatedManager':
            related_name = getattr(self.through, self.target_field_name).field._related_name
            filter_kwargs = {f'{related_name}__is_deleted': False}
            queryset = queryset.filter(is_deleted=False, **filter_kwargs)
        return queryset.filter(is_deleted=False)

    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        return self._apply_soft_delete_filter_if_needed(queryset)

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self._apply_soft_delete_filter_if_needed(queryset)
        return queryset.filter(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self._apply_soft_delete_filter_if_needed(queryset)
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

This modification ensures that softly deleted relationships are not displayed when accessed through the many-to-many relationship. If you encounter any issues or have further questions, feel free to ask!

You forgot to subclasss SoftDeleteModel, installing the package doesn't do anything, you need to actually use it
Quoted from their docs
class Article(SoftDeleteModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    # Following fields will be added automatically
    # is_deleted
    # deleted_at
    
    # Following managers will be added automatically
    # objects = SoftDeleteManager()
    # deleted_objects = DeletedManager()
    # global_objects = GlobalManager()


Apologies for the omission, that was an error in writing the message. I am indeed inheriting from SoftDeleteModel in my models, and the django-soft-delete package is correctly integrated into my project. Overall, the soft deletion mechanism works as expected in most cases, except for the many-to-many relationships I mentioned earlier.
